# Should I store compressed JSON in a CQL blob type or multiple Cassandra columns?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Purpose of the table is to maintain Audits.
Expected Behaviour: Huge writes with infrequent reads and no edits.

**Table Definition:**

```
PartitionKey(multiple columns), ClusteringKey(time-uuid), json BLOB;
```

**json** will hold Snappy.compressed bytes[]. I am trying to store high frequent large data in this table  with least partition size.

What do you think about a single BLOB column that holds compressed JSON or multiple columns in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

This is a better question for [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cassandra) as opposed to this forum, which is for Ops related questions. See [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community.html#discussions) for guidelines.

Having said that, if your total blob / record size falls within the recommended values, you could directly deal with JSON type. See [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_using/cqlSyntax.html#Limitations) for the size capacities.

> Blob size: 2 GB (less than 1 MB is recommended)

Alternative, and in fact the better route is for you to leverage [**Stargate**, the open data API gateway](http://stargate.io/docs/latest/develop/dev-with-doc.html) to work with JSON/Document like structures very easily and it automatically does the transformation for you very easily.

***Bonus Tip:*** If you don't want to self-manage Apache Cassandra™ & Stargate™ together yourself, you could leverage [***DataStax Astra DB***](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra/apis), which is a Serverless database that handles and make Stargate APIs (Document/JSON or REST or gRPC or GraphQL) readily available for the developers and also has a generous free tier to operate with.

Answer (score 1):

The decision on how to store your data really depends on how your application will be retrieving the data. When modelling data in Cassandra, you need to start by listing the application queries first. It is the complete opposite of data modelling for relational databases where you begin by designing tables.

In any case, there is no need to store the JSON data in a CQL `blob` column. As Madhavan stated in his answer, the recommended `blob` size is 1MB and is intended to store small images such as profile pictures. The cluster's performance will suffer if you attempt to store large blobs.

As an alternative to blobs, you can store JSON strings in a CQL `text` column if the application will only ever retrieve the data as a whole. If the application needs to retrieve individual fields from the document then you are better off mapping the JSON fields to CQL columns and storing the data accordingly.

Compression is irrelevant in this case because what matters is how the application will query the table. Cheers!